# Postman Bad Request - Request Too Long

Tags: api, asp.net-core, postman, identityserver3

I am using Asp.Net Core 3.1 API with Identity Server and I am using Postman as an API tester from long time and it is working perfect, but, after version update to 8.+.+ the Postman return me this error:

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Request Too Long</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.</p>
</BODY>
```

I putted in header **key** (Content-Type) and the **value** (application/json) and authorization is in type of **bearer** token with empty body.

I followed many questions to solve this issue like the bellow mentioned:

- [bad request - request too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052098/bad-request-request-too-long)
- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1124
- https://community.postman.com/t/400-bad-request/18252

> **How can I solve Postman (Bad Request - Request Too Long) issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research, it is very easy and simple way to delete the cookies from the Postman application as shown below:

[image: Cookies location]

Then delete the cookies as shown below:

[image: Delete cookies]

Now try to apply the request, it should work, but, **this is only temporary solution**, I hope there is a full solution from Postman team or someone.